# Ipad disable default multi gestures on my app

Tags: ios, ipad, gesture

I want to develop an ipad app for babies, i have noticed that when a baby uses an ipad, she will use many fingers, making the gestures for the ipad activate, like switch activities, check springboard, or close activity, or notifications

How can i disable this gestures in my app? (then i will implement my own gestures)

So is possible to disable the default gestures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the default gestures is not possible, you can only disable them from settings but still you can make up your own gestures
But keep in mind that system global gestures will have higher priority on your own gestures